# Optimally reach a number in deadfish!

Tags: code-golf, sequence, deadfish

## Goal:

Given any natural number `k` such that `k<256`, produce an deadfish program that gives the smallest solution possible.

## Background:

Deadfish is a joke esoteric programming language. It has a single unsigned byte of memory, called the `accumulator`, initialized at 0. There are four commands which form a string.

- `i` = `accumulator += 1`
- `d` = `accumulator -= 1`
- `s` = `accumulator = accumulator * accumulator`
- `o` = `print(accumulator)`

For example, the string `iiisis` would produce 100, as this would be the memory after each command:

- i -> 1
- i -> 2
- i -> 3
- s -> 9
- i -> 10
- s -> 100

## Specification:

- Read a number through any reasonable means (from a file, STDIO, or a function argument), and output an optimal string of commands producing that number.
- A solution is considered optimal if there are no solutions that use fewer commands.
- Output through any reasonable means (to a file, STDIO, or a return value).
- The accumulator may not exceed 256.

## Examples:

```
0 -> (Empty string, nothing, or error)
1 -> i
4 -> iis
8 -> iiisd
35 -> iisiisd
150 -> iiisiiisiiiiii
256 -> (Empty string, nothing, or error)
```

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40124/short-deadfish-numbers), although weirdly a code-challenge

Comment: I recommend you just say "input is guaranteed to be in the range 0-255" rather than including 256 in the test cases. also, should `0` be an empty string, not an error?

Comment: [This](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish/Constants) might be useful to test programs.

Comment: For 150, `iiissisisddd` is two instructions shorter than the given solution.

Comment: is `ioiisddsio` a valid output for 150? (+1 [1], print, +1 [2], +1 [3], ^2 [9], -1 [8], -1 [7], ^2 [49], +1 [50], print)

Comment: @GabrielBenamy The challenge says that the number must be in memory, not printed. Also, the official interpreter prints a newline after each number, which would render that solution invalid. (This was discussed in the [previous very similar challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40124/short-deadfish-numbers), where it was decided that it was valid in order to keep existing answers valid, though.)

Comment: LegionMammal978: 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 12, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150

Comment: @JulianLachniet `iiissisisddd` gives the shorter sequence 1, 2, 3, 9, 81, 82, 68, 69, 153, 152, 151, 150.

Comment: 82 -> 68 what the heck?

Comment: @JulianLachniet You state that the accumulator is an unsigned byte. 82^2 = 6724 ≡ 68 (mod 256).

Comment: You cannot go outside of the range. See edit to original post

Comment: Editing a question so that it invalidates an already-existing answer is bad practice.

Comment: What should the output be for `254`?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 164 bytes

```
a=#~Mod~256&;Switch[#2,#+1,"i",a[#-1],"d",_,"s"]&@@@Partition[FindShortestPath[Graph[Join@@(Thread[#->a@{#+1/.256->#,#-1,If[#<16,#^2,#]}]&)/@0~Range~255],0,#],2,1]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number as input and returns a list of instructions as output. Previous solution before requirements were changed:

#### Mathematica, 148 bytes

```
a=#~Mod~256&;Switch[#2,a[#+1],"i",a[#-1],"d",_,"s"]&@@@Partition[FindShortestPath[Graph[Join@@(Thread[#->a@{#+1,#-1,#^2}]&)/@0~Range~255],0,#],2,1]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number as input and returns a list of instructions as output. First, the edges for a graph of value transitions are generated. Then, `FindShortestPath` is used to find the shortest path from 0 to the requested value. Finally, pairs of values are taken and compared to find the instructions used. All outputs of this program can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Jj0eiftf).