# Auto-golf an esolang

Tags: code-golf, math, interpreter, metagolf, golfing-language

The lack of a social life drove a poor nerd into inventing another superfluous esolang called `!+~%`. For no good reason it initializes the accumulator with `6` and knows the following commands:

- `!` (`out(Accu); Accu = 6`) prints the accumulator value as decimal string to stdout (without newline) and resets the accumulator to its initial value `6`
- `+` (`Accu = Accu + 7`) adds `7` to the accumulator
- `~` (`Accu = uccA`) reverses the order of digits of the decimal value in the accumulator
- `%` (`Accu = 1Accu mod Accu`) replaces the accumulator by (`1` in front of the accumulator) modulo accumulator

Easier to understand with an example.
`%!+~!` produces `431`: Initially, the accumulator is `6`. `%` replaces it by `16 mod 6`, which is **`4`**, which is printed by the following `!`, while the accumulator is reset to `6`. `+` adds `7` and the `~` command reorders the `13` to be **`31`**, which is printed

For some boring-to-proof reason, the language allows to print any non-negative integer and code golfers around the world are seriously concerned about a flood of »what is the shortest code to produce 6431?« type of challenges. But you can prevent that!

**Task**: Write a program to output the code golfed `!+~%` code to produce a given number!

**Input**: A non-negative integer value in any format yo love (except `!+~%` ;-)

**Output**: The shortest `!+~%` code to produce that output (only one of the possible solutions)

**The shortest code** (in any language) **wins**.

**Test data**:

```
0     --> ++%!
1     --> +%%!
2     --> %%!
3     --> +~%%!
4     --> %!
5     --> +++%%!
6     --> !
12    --> +++%%+!
20    --> ++!
43    --> ++++~!
51    --> +%%++~!
654   --> !+~++~!
805   --> +++%~++~+~!
938   --> +%!+~+!
2518  --> %+++!%++!
64631 --> !%!!+~!
```

Comment: To prove that `the language allows to print any non-negative integer`, give code that generate 0-9 is enough, [wc]ould u add them? :)

Comment: Got they `7     +~%!
8     %+%+!
9     +%!`

Comment: see you require uniqueness

Comment: @l4m2 Actually having the numbers up to 6 is enough for the boring proof,, because you can construct everything else by adding 7.

Comment: Fun fact: the name of `!+~%` is the program which outputs 6, then sets the accumulator to 7.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 139 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

Expects the target integer as a string.

```javascript
n=>eval("for(k=0;(g=i=>i?g(i>>2,v=(i&=3)<3?[v+7,+[...v+''].reverse().join``,('1'+v)%v][i]:(r+=v,6),o+='+~%!'[i]):r)(k++,o=r='')!=n;v=6);o")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdHRboIwFAbge5@ikLC2OV0VUbbJDl75FIREgqhV05q69JJXZ2hR7F2//P1Pm54qV91qq65/n9rsmm6Pnca8cdWFhXtj2RlnGTugwlytD0zl@Vw4ZOoDE/6brAsHXwIKKaUDSktpG9fYW8O4PBmlt1vBaEzB8ciVhSpXzAI6kXJhACm0UUB75SvL2RlAGLRIKQ9QZw5TnpmQd1kxISSchYL0azolAFFwl3iUyMv8JQMkY6QdaDFmHvvlW@@zJ32ZH@R7nxHws2Yj@uLkLQWtL49f1p8bMF0@7nBvh/aJP8n3gP3revbJRZrE4SMZBcE9WU5k/yObqj4yTTAntdE3c2nkxRyYltdqt9E7lnICZM8057z7Bw)

Comment: [139](https://tio.run/##TdHRboIwFAbge5@ikLC2OV0VUbbJDl75FIREgqhV05q69JJXZ2hR7F2//P1Pm54qV91qq65/n9rsmm6Pnca8cdWFhXtj2RlnGTugwlytD0zl@Vw4ZOoDE/6brAsHXwIKKaUDSktpG9fYW8O4PBmlt1vBaEzB8ciVhSpXzAI6kXJhACm0UUB75SvL2RlAGLRIKQ9QZw5TnpmQd1kxISSchYL0azolAFFwl3iUyMv8JQMkY6QdaDFmHvvlW@@zJ32ZH@R7nxHws2Yj@uLkLQWtL49f1p8bMF0@7nBvh/aJP8n3gP3revbJRZrE4SMZBcE9WU5k/yObqj4yTTAntdE3c2nkxRyYltdqt9E7lnICZM8057z7Bw)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 47 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"%!+~"∞5в0δKÙ.Δ´6svyiˆ6ëÐÂr1ìs%s7+)yè}}ˆ¯JQ}1ªè
```

Brute-force, so pretty slow. Outputs as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AU0Asv9vc2FiaWX//yIlISt@IuKInjXQsjDOtEvDmS7OlMK0NnN2eWnLhjbDq8OQw4JyMcOscyVzNyspecOofX3LhsKvSlF9McKqw6j//zQzMQ) or [verify the first ten test cases](https://tio.run/##AVsApP9vc2FiaWX/VEZOwqk/IiDihpIgIj//IiUhK34i4oieNdCyMM60S8OZLs6UwrQ2c3Z5acuGNsOrw5DDgnIxw6xzJXM3Kyl5w6h9fcuGwq9Kwq5RfTHCqsOo/yz/).

**Explanation:**

```python
"%!+~"          # Push this string (which we use at the end)
 ∞              # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
  5в            # Convert each integer to a base-5 list
     δ          # Map over each inner list:
    0 K         #  Remove all 0s
       Ù        # Uniquify this infinite list of lists
 .Δ             # Pop and find the first list that's truthy for:
   ´            #  Empty the global array
   6            #  Push a 6 to start with
   s            #  Swap so the current list is at the top of the stack
    v           #  Pop and loop over its digits:
     yi         #   If the current digit is a 1:
       ˆ        #    Pop and add the current integer to the global array
       6        #    Push a 6 to reset
      ë         #   Else (the current digit is a 2, 3, or 4):
       Ð        #    Triplicate the current integer
        Â       #    Bifurcate the top; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
         r      #    Reverse the order of the (four items on the) stack
        1ì      #    Prepend a 1
          s     #    Swap the top two values
           %    #    Modulo
        s       #    Swap the top two values again
         7+     #    Add 7
            )   #    Wrap all three items into a list: [reverse(n),1n%n,n+7]
             yè #    Modular 0-based the current digit into it:
                #     2→n%7; 3→reverse(n); 4→1n%n
      }         #   Close the if-else statement
    }           #  Close the loop
     ˆ          #  Pop and add the final value to the global array as well
      ¯         #  Push the global array
       J        #  Join it together to a single string
        Q       #  Check whether it equals the (implicit) input-integer
  }1ª           # After we've found a result: append a 1
     è          # Modular 0-based index into the "%!+~"-string:
                #  1→!; 2→+; 3→~; 4→%
                # (after which this list of characters is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: »slow« as in »times out in input 12«, but is gets my upvote as I doubted golfing languages could crack the 50-byte-border on this.

Comment: @Philippos Welp, it's at least able to output the first ten test cases and example. I've had 'slow' programs before on other challenges that could barely output the first single test case. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>121</s> 119 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,a='',b,c=6,...s)=>n!=b?f(n,...s,a+'+',b,c+7,a+'-',b,+[...c+''].reverse().join``,a+'%',b,('1'+c)%c,a+'!',[b]+c,6):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcrBCoMwEATQe//Cg2zCrqGWEqGQ9kNEMG5jUSQppvj7qemteJt5M7PdbOR1en8qH54updEIT9YA0EBsNCmlojR3X5jhMe5T7mQR8HfAJucqZ2z3iRGgU6vb3BqdkGoOk@/7/CnzR0ANyLLkLAVQO3TIpOXNJg4@hsWpJbzEKM5Snv6lPsjlINeDaL1T@gI)

Modified from my https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265841/

Comment: Seems theoretically fine, but already crashes on input `5`

Comment: @Philippos Consumes too much stack. See Arnauld's solution for space-saving solution

Comment: @Philippos `ulimit -s unlimited; node --stack-size=99999 ea.js` outputs `+++%%!`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```
¹©ṃ“Ṿ;ɼ6“+7“D1;Ḍ%ṛṛ?“ṚḌ”v@ƒ6®Ḋ⁼
1ç1#ṃ“!+%~”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QzkMrH@5sftQw5@HOfdYn95gBWdrmQMLF0Prhjh7VhztnA5E9WH4WUOBRw9wyh2OTzA6te7ij61HjHi7Dw8sNlSEmKGqr1gHl////r2SqBAA)

Since [it’s permissible to output garbage to STDOUT while returning the actual answer as the pair of link’s return value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9658/42248), this is one byte shorter than the [previous version](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QzkMrH@5sftQw5@HOfdYn9zzcOdsMyNE2BxIuhtYPd/SoAoWAyB6sZBZQ4FHD3DKHY5PMgIKH1j3c0fWocQ@X4eHlhsoQcxS1Vev@//@vZKoEAA) which avoids doing so.

A pair of links called as a monad with a decimal string argument (e.g. `"5"`) and returning a string program in `!+~%` golfed to output the relevant number. Relatively slow, brute force solution.

Originally got stuck for any programs that included `%` on 0, but now fixed at the cost of three bytes (which I then managed to shave off another way!)

Comment: Not relatively slow, but absolutely slow: TiO times out on input `5`. (-; I have no supercomputer to verify it, so I simply trust you.

Comment: @Philippos there was actually a bug related to the way Jelly handles `10%0` and which meant it got into an infinite loop. Now fixed at a cost of 3 bytes - thanks for pointing out!

Comment: This proves that I can trust you! (-: The performance is now similar to other solutions. I'm not sure why solutions seem to scale worse than 5^n

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 156 bytes

*-2 bytes, thanks to STerliakov*

*simple brute force approach, takes input as a (decimal) string*

```python
def f(N):
 s="";S=[(6,s,s)]
 while s!=N:(a,b,s),*S=S;A=str(a);S+=[(6,b+"!",s+A),(a+7,b+"+",s),(int(A[::-1]),b+"~",s),(a and int("1"+A)%a,b+"%",s)]
 return b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZIxboMwFIbVlVPYjizZtZEgBEpAVOICWRijDEYBJVJFI0wUdeEi7ZClvVNzmmJokF_Y8Pe_358Nnz-nj-7w3lyv3-euduPfr31Vo5pteOIgnRGSFtmWRVJLzXcOuhyObxXSONskTMlyWJTPRVakeaa7limeFmKMl4JgIrXIuWRKvJh3QUyaHZuO5dskcf0dN8v9tKyQavbIQOKTYYwqAymZtm2r7tw2qJwcb0-3U2uiNSMe4XyBzOO6r0gIip2Z-ZBRmy0BAyiAYz2AKzhnkfDBBO4XAWpLzibzmLA9PYhtleBhUvS2jg_o0ApwFN5PMvqIfsSLmcdeaHGjZRKgYh3EdoSaErtiGfr_gfGqhg5MwQGiVRRMlqMDxUMDnj7x_Xf8Aw)

Comment: Very smart, but you should get rid of the doubled spaces for indenting.

Comment: You can do `(a,b,s),*S=S` instead of `.pop(0)` for -2.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>79</s> 65 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦ω⁶ω⟧Ｆυ¿¬ⅈ¿¬⌕ιθ⊟ι«≔§ι¹ηＦ⪪⟦η⁻⁶η!ω⁷+ω⁻⮌ηη~ω∧η⁻﹪ＸχＬηηη%⟧³⊞υＥκ⁺λ§ιμ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9NS8NAEIbP7a8YA8IsjmApVKWnXATBSNCLUHoIzba7uO7G/WgE0b@@Tppgb7P7zvvwzE41fucak3OdgsJEsOkJVgT9Vqzne@cBkwC9B3x2Ed9QnB8P2raoCT4Ff9Ze24i161ALsQZpgoTv@awMQR8slvHRtvJr2F4IAsXo2Yn92hkdcaMIKm1TwNUQEhQXBRsQ3PJ4NY5j/iKP0geJSkyLv2Nasso/pHJtMo5leulxcUPwJO0hKi5NrVPzstgSLAf16fCq6fCdoDaMMIw8O3/whaz8k/P98i5fH80f) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Based on @bsoelch's Python answer.

```
⊞υ⟦ω⁶ω⟧Ｆυ
```

Start a breath-first search with a state with no output, an accumulator of `6` and no commands yet.

```
¿¬ⅈ
```

Stop when a solution is found.

```
¿¬⌕ιθ⊟ι«
```

If a solution is found then print it, otherwise...

```
≔§ι¹η
```

Extract the current value from the state.

```
Ｆ⪪⟦η⁻⁶η!ω⁷+ω⁻⮌ηη~ω∧η⁻﹪ＸχＬηηη%⟧³
```

Create a list of updates, representing a string to output, an amount to add to the current value, and a command to execute, and split the list into groups of three elements.

```
⊞υＥκ⁺λ§ιμ
```

Add each group pairwise to the original state, creating four new states to be processed.

Comment: +1 It can really handle all test cases without timeout except for `805` (-:

Comment: @Philippos Well, it's exponentially slow in the length of the output...

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 165 bytes

```haskell
s%x=x++s%[(c++[p],x,y)|(c,a,o)<-x,(p,x,y)<-zip3"!+~%"[6,a+7,read$reverse$s a,read('1':s a)`mod`a][o++s a,o,o,o++['-'|a<1]]]
f n=[c|(c,_,o)<-show%[("",6,"")],o==n]!!0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZLRboMgFIazW5_iSGrUgInW6tyiT0LIRqxNzVox4ja3ND7B3mA3vWn2TNvTDG1F4QY-zvn_n8D3z57Ll-JwOJ8vr-3OS34v0uqyDmNpUSfHmNaMdOTDPTk54US4qdcRpx5R6n2WdYhM3FuIxoTje9IUfLtqireikcVKAh-BYwf2o9q4z0exfeaMCqWuzsQwlYPt2SeeBowxYwdVRvPB62n0knvxrnIgRGKCkMuIyLKKmaZ_Dft393XkZQUZ1E1ZtUB34AwtULqQZSDgBE5JQLiQetAWss25LCQzDL1WrdQAcHxQgwDC2DKRSwYUTMjSaH1DMwmnon5mm6lqApEWX2jFN6jt1osirB39iWr1UNfhXjsEOuuCxtHmaoH7BU38SBsNfD55CJObytChI0RBMl5HNZjWHCTexGEwqFumOWqw66NMP-kf)